# ExtJS: making Drag/Pan work without zoom

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2j3v&view/editor).

In this fiddle, when I zoom the chart a little after that click on Pan button. I am able to drag the chart to see other values.

**What I want is :-**

I should be able to drag the chart to left and right, right after the page is loaded.
So, we need to pre-set the zoom or enable the pan somehow?
How can we do that?

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Do you want char zooming disabled when you click on Pan ?

Comment: yes. I want - when the chat appears I should be able to see all the years by dragging it in right and left. I do not need the zoom, only drag/pan.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function **transformAxesBy** from the **PanZoom** interaction, after you render the chart:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function () {
        var axes = chart.getAxes();

        //Change the zoom value to fit your needs
        //function usage transformAxesBy(axes, panX, panY, zoomX, zoomY)
        chart.getInteractions()[0].transformAxesBy(axes, 0, 0, 1.5, 0);
    }
}
```

**I modified your fiddle code:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var chart;
        new LabChart({
            renderTo: document.body,
            width: 500,
            height: 220,
            margin: 30
        });
    }
});

Ext.define('LabChart', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'labchart',

    layout: 'fit',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.myDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            fields: ['time', 'data1'],
            data: [{
                "time": '2014',
                "data1": 15
            }, {
                "time": '2015',
                "data1": 20
            }, {
                "time": '2016',
                "data1": 25
            }, {
                "time": '2017',
                "data1": 20
            }]
        });
        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'cartesian',
            insetPadding: 10,
            interactions: [{
                type: 'panzoom',
                zoomOnPan: true,

                axes: {
                    left: {
                        allowPan: false,
                        allowZoom: true
                    },
                    bottom: {}
                }
            }],
            store: me.myDataStore,
            axes: [{
                type: 'numeric',
                fields: 'data1',
                position: 'left',
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 30,
                dashSize: 0,
            }, {
                type: 'numeric',
                fields: ['time'],
                minimum: 2000,
                maximum: 2019,
                grid: true
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                xField: 'time',
                yField: 'data1',
                label: {
                    field: 'data1'
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function () {
                    var axes = chart.getAxes();
                    chart.getInteractions()[0].transformAxesBy(axes, 0, 0, 1.5, 0);
                }
            }
        }];

        function resetChart() {
            var axes = chart.getAxes();

            axes[0].setVisibleRange([0, 1]);
            axes[1].setVisibleRange([0, 1]);
            chart.redraw();
        }
        me.tbar = [{
            text: 'Reset pan/zoom',
            handler: resetChart
        }];
        me.callParent();

        chart = this.down('cartesian'),
            panzoom = chart.getInteractions()[0];
        this.down('toolbar').add(panzoom.getModeToggleButton());
    }
});
```

Comment: The only problem here is , when I click on the chart thrice it gets zoomed out. Please let me know if you have solution for that as well ?

Comment: Just add this line in the afterRender event:   chart.getInteractions()[0].onDoubleTap = function (e){};